Text Image Binary Classifier without deep learning or tesseract
I have 20k small label images and each image has the word "Back" or "Front".
Image resolution is all (200px, 25px)

I can classify these images 100% accuracy with tesseract_OCR.
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
        if "Front" in txt:
            return "Front"
        if "Back" in txt:
            return "Back"

problem is, it is too slow(1 hour for 20k images) and need to install OCR packages.
I know even 3 layer Simple CNN also works well for it, but I think this problem seems to be solvable with simple algorithm without difficult techniques.
Can you recommend a new approach for me?
thank you.

potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78842114/is-a-siamese-network-the-right-algorithm-for-the-exposed-case

@ChristophRackwitz don't agree

I used the template_match function of OpenCV to compare whether the "Front" image saved as a sample matches the "Back" image.
I succeeded in reducing the time to about 1 minute.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

I am not sure, which architecture you use, but there are some potential solutions, which might help you:

Check what activation functions you have. For fast training, try to use Relu activations
Experiment with batch size of your dataloader - larger batch size leads to faster training, but can take more RAM
Check how many threads are used, when training your model. Sometimes you could speed up your training, if you have parallelism, when loading the data
Check the types of your numpy arrays (because your images are in the numpy arrays). Float16 could be a bit faster than Float32

I am sure, there are more ways to speed up training, but these are the most basic ones.
